# I can not start WAR project on GlassFish 4.1 in Intellij IDEA

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish

I tried create JSF+GlassFish 4.1 project and i have an error. I create Example Intellij IDEA project new project-> JSF -> finish. And i use GlassFish Server 4.1 wich install with NetBeans. When i start app i have this logs:

```
    Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
[2015-10-07 10:58:22,713] Artifact JsfApp:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
```

I have not password for domain and if i set password it not works too.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace tells you the problem. Something is holding on to the server.log.lck file. Probably you still have an old instance running.

Make sure Netbeans is not running. If it is, then Quit it.

In IDEA, look for the Run and Debug tabs and check them to make sure you don't have a Glassfish instance running in one of them. If you do then Stop it and when it is done stopping to just be sure also click the "X" icon in the Run and or Debug window. That will close the Run/Debug tab. I've seen that tab hold a lock on Glassfish log files sometimes.

Check the domain1/logs folder to make sure the .lck file is not there.

If it still is then you probably have a stuck Glassfish processes. In that case, completely quit IDEA.

Open up Task Manager and make sure "Show Processes For All Users" is checked and look for any java.exe processes are running and kill them. 
I am assuming you aren't on a shared server so that it will be ok to blindly kill any Java processes. You'll have to adjust accordingly for your environment.

At this point you shouldn't see the .lck file anymore and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that problem with change permissions on the folder of glassfish. If you have windows system, give all permissions on glassfish installation folder to system. (Poperties->Security)